# Two versions of rspec installed on my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've been attempting to make a start on learning Ruby/rspec. I read that rspec is now broken for Windows so an early version (2.14.1) should be installed instead. I started on testfirst's learn Ruby but kept getting errors whenever I attempted the "rake" task. I checked my rspec version and apparently I'm running 2.14.8. I thought maybe that was why I was getting some errors. So I typed into git "gem uninstall rspec" but it then said version 2.14.1 was uninstalled, not .8. So I checked to see if there were any versions of rspec installed on my computer and it says that 2.14.8 is still installed... now it won't let me uninstall it, even though I typed in "gem uninstall rspec -v 2.14.8."

I also tried to check the contents of version 2.14.8, but it couldn't find gem 'rspec' in default gem paths.

It's as if I had two versions of rpec on my laptop... how do I get rid of the .8 version?

Comment: What error you get when you run: `gem uninstall rspec -v 2.14.8`

Comment: There were no error messages at all, but when I checked rspec -v, it said I still had 2.14.8

Comment: What do you see when you do: `bundle show rspec`

Comment: Please paste the output of this: `gem list rspec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `gem uninstall rspec -v 2.14.8` did not work for you. Try cleaning up all the rspec version from your computer first by running:

```
gem cleanup rspec
```

Then, install the required version again.

#### Update:

Try:

```
gem uninstall -Iax rspec
```

If doesn't work, then try and remove the executables as well:

```
gem uninstall rspec-core
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to have any effect. I typed in rspec -v afterwards and version 2.14.8 was still listed.

Comment: what do you see when: `where rspec`
Please try my updated answer. That could work!
`gem uninstall rspec-core`

Comment: gem uninstall rspec-core worked, thank you! I also deleted -mocks and -expectations as they were still on my gem list.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear that RSpec is broken on Windows? AFAIK the current version (3.3.2) works just fine.

If you are going to learn Ruby and RSpec, you should also learn about using Rubygems and Bundler, since many projects rely on them. Install Bundler with:

```
gem install bundler
```

Create a new folder and CD into it, and then:

```
bundle init
```

This creates a file named "Gemfile" in the folder. This allows Bundler to manage the versions of gems used within your project. Edit the Gemfile and add this line:

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 3'
```

This tells Bundler that your project requires RSpec 3, and to install the latest version. Save the Gemfile, and then do:

```
bundle install
```

Bundler will install the RSpec gems and create a Gemfile.lock file that details the gem dependencies. To verify that the right version is installed:

```
rspec --version # => 3.3.2 (or whatever is the latest)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! After I'd uninstalled the rspec, I used this to install the latest version. I'll be sure to look into how to use Bundler.